# PHP/MySQL query deleting data but not re-inserting

Tags: php, mysql

I have this PHP Code:

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("DELETE from tickets_extra_emails where ticketnumber = :ticketnumber ");
    $stmt->execute(array(':ticketnumber' => $ticket["ticketnumber"]));
    $cc_contact_line = '';
    foreach(explode("\n", $_POST["cc_contacts"]) as $cc_contact_line) {
        //then insert new if its not blank
        if(filter_var($cc_contact_line, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            //see if it currently exists
            $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * from tickets_extra_emails where ticketnumber = :ticketnumber and email_address = :email_address ");
            $stmt->execute(array(':ticketnumber' => $ticket["ticketnumber"], ':email_address' => $cc_contact_line));
            $records = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            if(count($records) == 0) {
                echo 'insert '.$ticket["ticketnumber"].' - '.$cc_contact_line.'<br>';
                $stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("INSERT into tickets_extra_emails (ticketnumber, email_address) values (:ticketnumber, :email_address) ");
                $stmt->execute(array(':ticketnumber' => $ticket["ticketnumber"], ':email_address' => $cc_contact_line));
            }
        }
    }
```

that makes each line of a textarea a variable in a foreach loop.

if i put lines in the textarea and submit the form, it saves the data but then if there is already data in and i submit the form, it removes it.

what do i have wrong in my code? I have commented everything it does

Answer (score 0):

Theres a significant difference between MySQL `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

You will need to check against the database where you are inserting to and use a query to check if there is data existing in that row. Based on that query you can restructure your insert statement to be conditional and switch from an `INSERT` to an `UPDATE`.

Deleting existing data will not allow you to re-insert into the rows, the rows are existing and therefor require `UPDATE`. However if you are removing whole rows then you can indeed re insert the rows. I see this as not entirely efficient, when you can utilize the efficiency of `UPDATE` to its benefit here.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, fetchAll will fail if there are 0 rows, so you won't be able to run a count on the records.  Do you have errors enabled or logged?

I see what you are trying to do and why you want to delete then reinsert, although maybe not the best approach.

**Update:**  Apparently rowCount() shouldn't be relied on for selects, so I think the best alternative is to change your select query to select a count.  This will always return a value as long as the query is valid so you shouldn't have to worry about the fetch failing.  As you noticed below, I just changed the SELECT * to a SELECT count(*) so this will count how many rows match your constraints.  Then use fetchColumn() to select the first column of the first row (the count).

```
$stmt = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT count(*) from tickets_extra_emails where ticketnumber = :ticketnumber and email_address = :email_address ");
$stmt->execute(array(':ticketnumber' => $ticket["ticketnumber"], ':email_address' => $cc_contact_line));
$records = $stmt->fetchColumn();
```